# Как удалить файлы и папки во вложеных неудаляя папки верхнего уровня

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

есть такой примерно каталог:

- scan

  - FIO1

    - dir1
    - file1
    - dir2
    - file1
    - file2
    - Читай.txt
  - FIO2

    - dir1
    - file1
    - file2
    - Читай.txt

Задача удалить все файлы и каталоги кроме 1 го уровня (FIO1,FIO2....),а так же файлов Читай.txt

пробовал типа rm `ls | grep -v "^Читай.tXt$\|^info.txt$"` но это удаляет только в текущей папке через find удаляется все и везде.

Comment: у grep есть флаг -r  - recursive

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать, может придется подрегулировать

```
find ./ -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3  -type d,f -not -name Читай.txt -delete
```

текущая директория перед scan, т.е. `ls` покажет `scan/`